# Pandas Group 2-D NumPy Data by Range of Values

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have a large data set in the form of a 2D array. The 2D array represents continuous intensity data and I want to use this to create another 2D array of the same size only this time, the values are grouped into discreet values. In other words if I have a 2D array like this,

```
[(11, 23, 33, 12),
 (21, 31, 13, 19),
 (33, 22, 26, 31)]
```

The output would be as shown below with the values from 10 to 19 assigned to 1, 20 to 29 assigned to 2 and 30 to 39 assigned to 3.

```
[(1, 2, 3, 1),
 (2, 3, 1, 1),
 (3, 2, 2, 3)]
```

More ideally, I would like to make these assignments based on percentiles. As in, the values that fall into the top ten percent get assigned to 5, the values in the top 20 to 4 and so on.

My data set is in a NumPy format. I have looked at the functions `groupby` but this does not seem to allow me to specify ranges. I have also looked at `cut` however cut only works on 1D arrays. I have considered running the cut function through a loop as I go through each row of the data but I am concerned that this may take too much time. My matrices could be as big as 4000 rows by 4000 columns.

Comment: Do you really want your output to be tuples like that, or are you fine with just a regular array

Comment: Fine with a regular array @user3483203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `stack` the dataframe to have a 1-D representation and then apply `cut`. After that you can `unstack` it.

```
[tuple(x) for x in (pd.cut(pd.DataFrame(a).stack(), bins=[10,20,30,40], labels=False)+1).unstack().values]
```

**OR** (using [@user3483203](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3483203/user3483203)'s magic)

```
[tuple(x) for x in np.searchsorted([10, 20, 30, 40], np.array(a))]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 1), 
 (2, 3, 1, 1), 
 (3, 2, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: `np.searchsorted([10, 20, 30, 40], np.array(a))`

Comment: @user3483203, you made much simpler. Thanks.

Comment: figured out you can do the percentage thing by setting b=np.percentile(zData, [0,97,98,99.8,100]) and letting the bins = b. and similar replacement with @user3483203 's version. Thank you

Comment: Both of these solutions worked on the numpy array when I had assigned the result to another variable. The original data frame had column and row headings and I tried to perform this on the original format to see if I could preserve the information in the headings. The only way I can think of doing this now is by creating a new data frame and copying the heading information as well as the grouped intensity 2D array. Do you know if there is a better way?